# How to make future-proof project with Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dependency-management, carthage

I have a project in which I use Carthage for my dependency management. I want it to be easy to clone and run right away for *Future Me*©.  I'm commitning *Carthage/Checkouts* already, but some frameworks come with a prebuild binary. You can force downloading sources with `‑‑no‑use‑binaries` flag, but adding a framework file would be easier. What (and why) should and should not be in my .gitignore to make the project future-proof?

Comment: SDK updates can bug the Future Me as well. For instance, after updating Xcode to 7.2 with watchOS 2.1, I couldn't build Carthage dependencies to support watchOS 2.0 anymore to meet the build requirements. I might add the frameworks to repository to make it possible to build straight after checkout but there's a lot more in the Build folder.

Comment: We shouldn't add binaries to repos. They go in the release section of github inside .zip files